# Can I get Max parallel http connections in a browser with javascript?

Tags: javascript, http

I want Something like this

```
var maxConnections = window.maxConenctions();
```

Please don't answer me with how many parallel connections  every browser has :)

Comment: I dont think this is available via the the common BOMs, however if you are developing a cordova app for example, you may be able to create cordova plugin to expose an JS API to access this detail.

Comment: what are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I have wto ways to do s.th : first solution is faster when number of calls are < maxConnections and seconde is faster when > maxConnections. for now i use a constant number (=8 with IE10) but i want this to be dynamic for evry browser

Comment: you can use browser detection (like https://github.com/ded/bowser) to get the browser version and match it to suitable max connection cout, and default to a safe value when its a unrecognised browser

Comment: Problem when client change config of max conenctions

Comment: is this an edge case in your scenario, typical users dont adjust their defaults?

Comment: users in my case change this param often